# OOP design skill additional effect in RPG style game

Tags: c#, oop

Creating a RPG related program, I would like to add various additional effects to my characters skills (damage over time, buff, etc...)

So far I did something looking like this (C# Syntax)

```
public class Paladin : Character
{
   public Paladin()
   {
      BaseMP = 7080;
      caster = false;
      baseGCD = 2.43;
      aadelay = 2.24;
      aapotency = AAPotency.Attack;

      Moveset = new List<IMove>()
      {
        new Weaponskill("Fast Blade", "", 150, 150, false, false, baseGCD, null),
        new Weaponskill("Riot Blade", "Fast Blade", 100, 230, false, false, baseGCD, new RiotBlade_Effect()),
        new Weaponskill("Goring Blade", "Riot Blade", 100, 240, false, false, baseGCD, new DoT(50, 24)),
        new Spell("Holy Spirit", 430, 1440, false, 2.5, null),
        new Ability("Requiescat", 350, true, 60, false, new Requiescat_Effect()),        
      };
    }
}
```

`Weaponskill`, `Spell` and `Ability` are all implementations of Interface `ISkill`, which represent one of my characters skills.

The last parameter of their constructor is either null if there is no special effect, or should contains the special effect of this skill.

To implement them, i thought about a strategy design pattern (or what I believe is a strategy design pattern, first time i try to implement it).

```
 public interface IStrategy
 {
   void execute();
 }

 public class RiotBlade_Effect : IStrategy
 {
     public RiotBlade_Effect()
     {

     }

     public void execute()
     {

     }
}
```

I got two problems.

First, how can the `IStrategy` implementation can know my `Character` properties if I need to change them? (for exemple, if I want to lower or increase one of the properties set in `Paladin()`).

Second, how can I handle multiple possible return types for `execute()`, depending on the effect I'll implement?

Comment: [Eric Lippert's conclusion on OOP](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/)

Comment: There is a [Game Development SE site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), in case you find it helpful down the line.

Comment: @gms0ulman I thought it was a general OOP design question and could help other after my own self. RPG style exemple that makes it easier for everyone to understand, but I could have made it with finance equity derivatives.

Comment: @YthioCsi I agree it's a good question (+1'd) - that was just an FYI

Comment: Ah i missunderstood. My apologies.

Comment: @gmd0ulman After researching i bit, i think a visitor pattern would do the trick, isn't it ?